# Python BeautifulSoup get text from HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have some HTML code like this:

```
<p>aaa</p>bbb
<p>ccc</p>ddd
```

How can I get 'bbb' and 'ddd'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the subsequent sibling of each `p` tag (note this is very specific to this text, so hopefully it can be expanded to your situation):

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: html = """\
   ...: <p>aaa</p>bbb
   ...: <p>ccc</p>ddd"""

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

In [4]: [p.next_sibling for p in soup.findAll('p')]
Out[4]: [u'bbb\n', u'ddd']
```

This picks up the trailing newline, so you can strip it off if need be:

```
In [5]: [p.next_sibling.strip() for p in soup.findAll('p')]
Out[5]: [u'bbb', u'ddd']
```

The general idea is that you locate the tag(s) before your target text and then find the next sibling element, which should be your text.

Answer (score -2):

It is easier if you enclose the values ('bbb', 'ddd') into a tag (as `<span>`)

Then you can get it using: soup('span')

Comment: What if the webpage isn't his??

Comment: but there is no tag enclose the values